# Wierd JSPX problems with <c:if>

Tags: html, jstl, jspx

I am writing code like this in a JSPX file,

```
<table>
  <c:forEach var="var" items="${items}" varStatus="status">

    <c:if test="${(status.index) % 4 == 0}">
      <tr>
    </c:if>

    <td>some contents</td>

    <c:if test="${(status.index+1) % 4 == 0 || status.last}">
      </tr>
    </c:if>

  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

The problem is, the `<tr>` and `</tr>` will cause compilation errors in JSPX. It will say "`<tr>` should be ended with a `</tr>`". However, it is fine with JSP.

Is there any way to do things like this in JSPX? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could do the following:

```
<table>
  <c:forEach var="var" items="${items}" varStatus="status">

    <c:if test="${(status.index) % 4 == 0}">
      <c:out value="&lt;tr&gt;" escapeXml="false"/>
    </c:if>

    <td>some contents</td>

    <c:if test="${(status.index+1) % 4 == 0 || status.last}">
      <c:out value="&lt;/tr&gt;" escapeXml="false"/>
    </c:if>

  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. It is said that JSPX will not evaluate EL until the document is correct and well formatted. But is it commonly used in JSPX? That is really ugly...